# How to handle NaNs returned from 'roc_curve' before passing to 'auc'?

Tags: scikit-learn

I am using 'roc_curve' from the metrics model in scikit-learn. The example shows that `'roc_curve'` should be called before `'auc'` similar to:

```
fpr, tpr, thresholds = metrics.roc_curve(y, pred, pos_label=2)
```

and then:

```
metrics.auc(fpr, tpr)
```

However the following error is returned:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "analysis.py", line 207, in <module>
    r = metrics.auc(fpr, tpr)   File "/apps/anaconda/1.6.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/metrics.py", line 66, in auc
    x, y = check_arrays(x, y)   File "/apps/anaconda/1.6.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 215, in check_arrays
    _assert_all_finite(array)   File "/apps/anaconda/1.6.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 18, in _assert_all_finite
    raise ValueError("Array contains NaN or infinity.") ValueError: Array contains NaN or infinity.
```

What does it mean in terms or results/is there a way to overcome this?

Comment: why did you use `pos_label=2`? this means that your positive label is "2" - is this true in your case? if you have only "0" and "1" as your labels that would explain the NaNs :)

Answer (score 1):

You state this line:

```
fpr, tpr, thresholds = metrics.roc_curve(y, pred, pos_label=2)
```

which leads to the conclusion that you may have copied the sklearn example which also uses "pos_label=2".

However, in most cases you want the "pos_label" to be 1. So if your code outputs probabilities and they are between 0 and 1, then your pos_label should be 1.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to us roc_curve to evaluate a multiclass classifier? In other words, if you are using roc_curve on a classification problem that is not binary, then this won't work correctly. There is math out there for multidimensional ROC analysis, but the current ROC methods in python don't implement them.

To evaluate multiclass problems trying using methods like: confusion_matrix and classification_report from sklearn, and kappa() from skll.